# Excel::Writer::XLSX write a formula, open this excel file and close it with an alert dialog

Tags: excel, perl

I use Excel::Writer::XLSX to write data to an excel file. There are two formulas used to caculate the final value. But now I have a problem, when opening the excel file and then close it, nothing operation on the excel file. An alert dialog always pops out. The message of the alert dialog like this:
Do you want to save the changes that you made to 1.xlsx?

The alert dialog will make user confused.

If the formulas doesn't exist, the alert dialog will not show. 
If I directly write a formula in an excel file. If opening it again, When closing it, the alert dialog will not show. 
So the only difference is that the formula is created by Excel::Writer::XLSX module.
Who can help me to explain why the strange thing happens and tell me how to fix it in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Excel::Writer::XLSX only writes the text representation of the formula to the XLSX file. It doesn't write the actual calculated value of the formula since it doesn't have a spreadsheet engine to calculate the results.

Instead it sets a flag to tell Excel to calculate the formulas when it loads the file. Excel does this and the results of the formula are displayed.

So when Excel loads an Excel::Writer::XLSX with formulas it is updating it and as a result it asks if you want to save the file when you close it.

Comment: Thanks for your telling me the root reason, but how to solve the problem. I don't hope everytime I open this file with Mirosoft Office, it always the alert dialog when I close the file. It makes me not to know what happens.

Comment: To avoid this warning you would have to supply the calculated value for each formula that you use via the `value` parameter of [write_formula()](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm). The module would also have to be extended to support manual calculation of formulas instead of automatic calulation. This would avoid the warning on save but might equally confuse users if their calculations aren't updated automatically.

Comment: But I tried it, seems that it still doesn't work. This is my case:    $worksheet->write_formula( 'A4', '=SIN(PI()/4)', $format, '0.707107' );

Comment: As I said in the previous comment "the module would also have to be extended to support manual calculation of formulas instead of automatic calculation". If you add a feature request for manual calculation to the GitHub issue tracker I'll add it in a future release. (I'm the author btw in case that isn't clear.)